# Init service not running in yocto.. pidof not found error

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, pid, init

I am trying to run a service on startup in Yocto image. My hardware is x64 and I copied service recipe from the meta-skeleton layer.

When I flashed the latest image with this service, and looked at "ps", the service was not running.

I manually jump to init.d directory and executed `./infusion start` command and I got the following error:

```
./infusion: line 192: pidof: not found
ERROR: command pidof not found
Starting infusion ...
```

How to add pidof utility to my image. I am generating core-image-minimal image.

Thanks for your time. Appreciate your efforts..

Comment: I found pidof utility in /bin folder.. Running pidof throws:"-sh: pidof: not found
"

Answer (score 0):

I think the default path is not set so its not able to find it please specify
it using absolute path in the script where you are calling it e.g.

```
/bin/pidof
```

other option is to add

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

at top of your init script might help

Comment: cd to /bin and ./pidof is also throwing the same error. Not found

Comment: can you check if pidof binary exist in rootfs at all? usually this binary is in /bin

Comment: Yes.. It is present in /bin folder

Comment: Can you check if its a binary or a shell script ?

Comment: it is binary file

Comment: can you add export PATH=$PATH:/bin and then run pidof init

Comment: I wonder if pidof is targetted correctly for your processor architecture. May be post the binary somewhere to take a look

Comment: `file /bin/pidof` should help finding the target architecture which the binary is build for.

Comment: I'd start with 'ls -l /bin/pidof' - it may be a symlink to non-existent target.

Comment: "Not found" error is also printed when ELF binary references 'interpreter' that is not available. 'strings /bin/pidof | grep /lib' should show it (if 'strings' is available - otherwise copy file to host somehow and try there)